# Can't change properties of referenced object in array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, reference

I am trying to create a grid-based map made out of 20*20 tiles, but I'm having trouble making the tiles communicate and access properties of adjacent ones.

This is the code used trying to accomplish this:

```
var tileArray:Array = []

class Tile:SKSpriteNode
{
    var upperAdjacentTile:Tile?

    override init()
    {
        let texture:SKTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "TempTile")
        let size:CGSize = CGSizeMake(CGFloat(20), CGFloat(20))

        super.init(texture: texture, color: nil, size: size)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setAdjacentTile(tile:Tile)
    {
        upperAdjacentTile = tile
    }
}

for i in 0..<10
{
    for j in 0..<10
    {
        let tile:Tile = Tile()
        tile.position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(i) * 20, CGFloat(j) * 20 )
        tile.name = String(i) + String(j)

        //checks if there is a Tile above it (aka previous item in array)
        if(i+j != 0)
        {
                                          //The position of this tile in array minus one
            tile.setAdjacentTile(tileArray[(j + (i * 10)) - 1] as Tile)
        }

        tileArray.append(tile)
    }
}

println(tileArray[10].upperAdjacentTile) //Returns the previous item in tileArray
println(tileArray[9].position) //Returns the position values of same item as above
println(tileArray[10].upperAdjacentTile.position) //However, this doesn't work
```

Why can't i access/change the properties of the tile referenced in "upperAdjacentTile"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`upperAdjacentTile` is an Optional you have to unwrap first (since it can be `nil`).

```
// will crash if upperAdjacentTile is nil
println(tileArray[10].upperAdjacentTile!.position)
```

or

```
if let tile = tileArray[10].upperAdjacentTile {
    // will only run if upperAdjacentTile is not nil
    println(tile.position)
}
```

**Edit**

As rintaro suggested you also have to specify the type of the objects the array contains:

```
var tileArray = [Tile]()
```

Comment: Error reads "Tile does not have a member named 'position'", even though Tile is subclass of SKSpriteNode. Codehints even lets me autocomplete 'position', so this doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @user3368104 you should explicitly define the type of array like `var tileArray:Array<Tile> = []`